# Magento modify customer activation module for customer group

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to modify [Netzarbeiter's Customer Activation](https://github.com/Vinai/customer-activation/blob/master/app/code/community/Netzarbeiter/CustomerActivation/Model/Observer.php) module so the extension only flags a certain customer group for admin approval. The following is the block of code I have been modifying.

```
/**
 * Flag new accounts as such
 *
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 */
public function customerSaveBefore($observer)
{

    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
    //$customer_group_id=$customer->getCustomerGroupId();
    $customer_group_id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(); 

    Mage::log('The customer group id is'. $customer_group_id , null, 'caitlin.log');

    if ($customer_group_id=1)
        Mage::log('I have a General group ID \n',null,'caitlin.log');
    else if ($customer_group_id=5)
        Mage::log('I have a Test group ID \n',null,'caitlin.log');
    else
        Mage::log('I dont understand! \n',null,'caitlin.log');

    $storeId = Mage::helper('customeractivation')->getCustomerStoreId($customer);

    if (Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_MODULE_DISABLED, $storeId))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!$customer->getId())
    {
        if ($customer_group_id =5){
            $defaultStatus = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_DEFAULT_STATUS, $storeId);
            $customer->setCustomerActivated($defaultStatus);
            $customer->setCustomerActivationNewAccount(true);
        }
        else{
            $customer->setCustomerActivated('Yes');
            $customer->setCustomerActivationNewAccount(false);
            Mage::log('This block initiated',null,'caitlin.log');
        }
    }
}
```

So far, the customer ID is being logged correctly, but when registering a customer of the customer group ID "1" the program is not entering into the else statement with the "This block has been initiated" log. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong or has another idea for getting the program to automatically flag a particular customer group for approval only?

The whole model below:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * package    Netzarbeiter_CustomerActivation
 * copyright  Copyright (c) 2012 Vinai Kopp http://netzarbeiter.com/
 * license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

class Netzarbeiter_CustomerActivation_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    const XML_PATH_MODULE_DISABLED = 'customer/customeractivation/disable_ext';

    const XML_PATH_DEFAULT_STATUS = 'customer/customeractivation/activation_status_default';

    const XML_PATH_ALWAYS_NOTIFY_ADMIN = 'customer/customeractivation/always_send_admin_email';

    /**
     * Fired on customer_login event
     * Check if the customer has been activated (via adminhtml)
     * If not, through login error
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function customerLogin($observer)
    {
        if (Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_MODULE_DISABLED))
        {
            return;
        }

        if ($this->_isApiRequest())
        {
            return;
        }

        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

        if (!$customer->getCustomerActivated())
        {
            /*
             * Fake the old logout() method without deleting the session and all messages
             */
            $session->setCustomer(Mage::getModel('customer/customer'))->setId(null);

            if ($this->_checkRequestRoute('customer', 'account', 'createpost'))
            {
                /*
                 * If this is a regular registration, simply display message
                 */
                $message = Mage::helper('customeractivation')->__('Please wait for your account to be activated');

                $session->addSuccess($message);
            }
            else
            {
                /*
                 * All other types of login
                 */
                Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('customeractivation')->__('This account is not activated.'));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Flag new accounts as such
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function customerSaveBefore($observer)
    {

        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        //$customer_group_id=$customer->getCustomerGroupId();
        $customer_group_id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(); 

        Mage::log('The customer group id is'. $customer_group_id , null, 'caitlin.log');

        if ($customer_group_id=1)
            Mage::log('I have a General group ID \n',null,'caitlin.log');
        else if ($customer_group_id=5)
            Mage::log('I have a Test group ID \n',null,'caitlin.log');
        else
            Mage::log('I dont understand! \n',null,'caitlin.log');

        $storeId = Mage::helper('customeractivation')->getCustomerStoreId($customer);

        if (Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_MODULE_DISABLED, $storeId))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!$customer->getId())
        {
            if ($customer_group_id =5){
                $defaultStatus = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_DEFAULT_STATUS, $storeId);
                $customer->setCustomerActivated($defaultStatus);
                $customer->setCustomerActivationNewAccount(true);
            }
            else{
                $customer->setCustomerActivated('Yes');
                $customer->setCustomerActivationNewAccount(false);
                Mage::log('This block initiated',null,'caitlin.log');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Send out emails
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function customerSaveAfter($observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

        $storeId = Mage::helper('customeractivation')->getCustomerStoreId($customer);

        if (Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_MODULE_DISABLED, $storeId))
        {
            return;
        }

        $defaultStatus = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_DEFAULT_STATUS, $storeId);

        try
        {
            if (Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin())
            {
                if (!$customer->getOrigData('customer_activated') && $customer->getCustomerActivated())
                {
                    // Send customer email only if it isn't a new account and it isn't activated by default
                    if (!($customer->getCustomerActivationNewAccount() && $defaultStatus))
                    {
                        Mage::helper('customeractivation')->sendCustomerNotificationEmail($customer);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ($customer->getCustomerActivationNewAccount())
                {
                    // Only notify the admin if the default is deactivated or the "always notify" flag is configured
                    $alwaysNotify = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_ALWAYS_NOTIFY_ADMIN, $storeId);
                    if (!$defaultStatus || $alwaysNotify)
                    {
                        Mage::helper('customeractivation')->sendAdminNotificationEmail($customer);
                    }
                }
                $customer->setCustomerActivationNewAccount(false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            Mage::throwException($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function salesCovertQuoteAddressToOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var $address Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address */
        $address = $observer->getEvent()->getAddress();
        $this->_abortCheckoutRegistration($address->getQuote());
    }

    /**
     * Abort registration during checkout if default activation status is false.
     *
     * Should work with: onepage checkout, multishipping checkout and custom
     * checkout types, as long as they use the standard converter model
     * Mage_Sales_Model_Convert_Quote.
     *
     * Expected state after checkout:
     * - Customer saved
     * - No order placed
     * - Guest quote still contains items
     * - Customer quote contains no items
     * - Customer redirected to login page
     * - Customer sees message
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    protected function _abortCheckoutRegistration(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote $quote)
    {
        if (Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_MODULE_DISABLED, $quote->getStoreId()))
        {
            return;
        }

        if ($this->_isApiRequest())
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() && !$quote->getCustomerIsGuest())
        {
            // Order is being created by non-activated customer
            $customer = $quote->getCustomer()->save();
            if (! $customer->getCustomerActivated()) {
                // Abort order placement
                // Exception handling can not be assumed to be useful

                // Todo: merge guest quote to customer quote and save customer quote, but don't log customer in

                // Add message
                $message = Mage::helper('customeractivation')->__(
                    'Please wait for your account to be activated, then log in and continue with the checkout'
                );
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($message);

                // Handle redirect to login page
                $targetUrl = Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login');
                $response = Mage::app()->getResponse();

                if (Mage::app()->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
                    // Assume one page checkout
                    $result = array('redirect' => $targetUrl);
                    $response->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
                } else if ($response->canSendHeaders(true)) {
                    // Assume multishipping checkout
                    $response->clearHeader('location')
                        ->setRedirect($targetUrl);
                }
                $response->sendResponse();
                /* ugly, but we need to stop the further order processing */
                exit();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return true if the reqest is made via the api
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _isApiRequest()
    {
        return Mage::app()->getRequest()->getModuleName() === 'api';
    }

    /**
     * Check the current module, controller and action against the given values.
     *
     * @param string $module
     * @param string $controller
     * @param string $action
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _checkRequestRoute($module, $controller, $action)
    {
        $req = Mage::app()->getRequest();
        if (strtolower($req->getModuleName()) == $module
            && strtolower($req->getControllerName()) == $controller
            && strtolower($req->getActionName()) == $action
        )
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Add customer_activated attribute to grid.
     *
     * Thanks to Rouven Alexander Rieker <rouven.rieker@itabs.de> for the base code.
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function coreBlockAbstractToHtmlBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if (Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_MODULE_DISABLED))
        {
            return;
        }

        /** @var $block Mage_Core_Block_Abstract */
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        if ($block->getId() == 'customerGrid')
        {
            /** @var $helper Netzarbeiter_CustomerActivation_Helper_Data */
            $helper = Mage::helper('customeractivation');

            // Add the attribute as a column to the grid
            $block->addColumnAfter(
                'customer_activated',
                array(
                    'header' => $helper->__('Customer Activated'),
                    'align' => 'center',
                    'width' => '80px',
                    'type' => 'options',
                    'options' => array(
                        '0' => $helper->__('No'),
                        '1' => $helper->__('Yes')
                    ),
                    'default' => '0',
                    'index' => 'customer_activated',
                    'renderer' => 'customeractivation/adminhtml_widget_grid_column_renderer_boolean'
                ),
                'customer_since'
            );

            // Set the new columns order.. otherwise our column would be the last one
            $block->sortColumnsByOrder();

        }

    }

    /**
     * Add customer activation option to the mass action block.
     *
     * This can't be done during the block abstract e
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function adminhtmlBlockHtmlBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        // Check the grid is the customer grid
        if ($observer->getBlock()->getId() != 'customerGrid')
        {
            return;
        }

        // Check if there is a massaction block and if yes, add the massaction for customeractivation
        $massBlock = $observer->getBlock()->getMassactionBlock();
        if ($massBlock)
        {
            /** @var $helper Netzarbeiter_CustomerActivation_Helper_Data */
            $helper = Mage::helper('customeractivation');

            $massBlock->addItem(
                'customer_activated',
                array(
                    'label' => $helper->__('Customer Activated'),
                    'url' => Mage::getUrl('customeractivation/admin/massActivation'),
                    'additional' => array(
                        'status' => array(
                            'name' => 'customer_activated',
                            'type' => 'select',
                            'class' => 'required-entry',
                            'label' => $helper->__('Customer Activated'),
                            'values' => array(
                                '1' => $helper->__('Yes'),
                                '0' => $helper->__('No')
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add the customer_activated attribute to the customer grid collection
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function eavCollectionAbstractLoadBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if (Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_MODULE_DISABLED))
        {
            return;
        }

        // Cheap check to reduce overhead on product and category collections
        if (Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName() !== 'customer')
        {
            return;
        }

        /** @var $collection Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection */
        $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();

        // Only add attribute to customer collections
        $customerTypeId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getEntityType('customer')->getId();
        $collectionTypeId = $collection->getEntity()->getTypeId();
        if ($customerTypeId == $collectionTypeId)
        {
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('customer_activated');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple mistake. You are using the assignment operator `=` rather than the comparison operator `==`.

Comment: THANKYOU! Wow! Hhaha. I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: *Everyone* has made that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i tried with you code and i cant get customer group id.

i tried

```
$customer_group_id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
```

and finally got it by using this

```
$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

$customer_group = $customer->getGroupId();
```